# Limited amount of iDevices on Developer ID

Tags: ios, xcode

I personally just have a personal developer account, but I was wondering if the restrictions of having only 100 iDevices also falls under paid developer accounts or is that restriction only for free developing account?

Answer (score 0):

It applies to paid dev accounts as well (which im on)

> Please note that a maximum of 100 devices can be included in your file and it may take a few minutes to process.

Except this statement seems a bit ambiguous, since it says "a maximum of 100 devices can be included in your file" but does that mean you can upload multiple files of 100 each?

I would assume its 100 max overall

Comment: It is kind of confusing. Would this be for Enterprise Developer Licenses as well then?

Comment: possibly, i guess apple doesnt want you distributing your app freely, bypassing the app store, so they just put a limit

Comment: with the Enterprise license you don't have to distribute your App through the App Store. I can just be installed. Weird...

Comment: those devices probably wouldnt need to be registered as development devices then, so wouldnt need to add them in the first place therefore wouldnt count towards your limit, since they would sign with a release provisioning profile of some kind most likely, just theorising though, havnt done an enterprise app before